# How to install & run Gimp using snap

Tags: terminal

I want to:

1. Ask if user has installed snap. If not run a script that installs snap & exit, if yes continue.
2. Install gimp, then show a message indicating that gimp install is complete.
3. Ask user if they want to run gimp. If yes run gimp, if no exit script.

Comment: Why do you want to use snap instead of the system's package manager?

Comment: When you say "ask if user has installed snap", do you mean prompt the user asking them if they installed snap, or do you want the script to auto-detect if snap is installed?

Comment: @ShaneBishop I'm not that familiar with linux, but I have a chromebook with linux support so I figured I would play around with & I was under the impression that using snap was more efficient because it includes everything in one package instead of having to still install all of the dependencies seperately anyway. At least that was my understanding of snap anyway.Yes, I meant to prompt them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `sh`-compliant script. Comments are provided to explain what different parts of the script do.

I assumed it was okay to install `snap` with the `apt` package manager, because the OP did not specify how to install `snap`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Exit early if any command fails
set -e

installSnap() {
    # Assumption: This script is run only on Debian-based Linux distributions
    echo 'snap not installed, installing snap...'
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install snapd
    echo 'snap installed. Log out and back in again before using snap.'
}

# If snap is not installed, install snap and exit
command -v snap || { installSnap && echo 'Exiting install script.' && exit 0; }

# Install GIMP
echo 'Installing GIMP...'
snap install gimp
echo 'GIMP installed.'

# Prompt user for input, and store input in answer
printf 'Would you like to run GIMP (y/n)? '
read -r answer

# If answer begins with 'Y' or 'y', start gimp
# Run gimp in background with nohup so gimp will continue running after
# this script terminates
# We likely aren't interested in gimp's output, so redirect it to /dev/null
[ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ] && nohup gimp > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```